# get target type of a pointer in c++ template

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have written a template function which may be passed either a QTcpServer or a QBluetoothServer. It gets the next pending connection and binds a couple of it's event handlers. (the real function also contains some error handling and other stuff but they are not relavent to the question so I have left them out).

```
template <typename T> static void clientConnected(T * server) {
    auto clientsocket = server->nextPendingConnection();
```

clientsocket will either be a QTcpSocket or a QBluetoothSocket depending on the type of server.

I can bind the readyRead signal using the common base class QIODevice.

```
    QObject::connect(clientsocket,&QIODevice::readyRead, [=](){readyRead(clientsocket);});
```

However there is no such common base class for the disconnected signal. So I need to know what type clientsocket is a pointer to in order to select the correct signal to bind. I came up with.

```
    QObject::connect(clientsocket,&std::remove_reference<decltype(*clientsocket)>::type::disconnected, [=](){readyRead(clientsocket);});
```

Which works, but seems rather unweildly, is there a more concise way to get the type of the target of a pointer?

---

As requested there is a minimal compilable example below in which any alternate soloutions can be tested.

```
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QBluetoothServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QBluetoothSocket>

template <typename T> static void clientConnected(T * server) {
    auto clientsocket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    QObject::connect(clientsocket,&std::remove_reference<decltype(*clientsocket)
}

void baz() {
    QTcpServer * foo = new QTcpServer();
    clientConnected(foo);
    QBluetoothServer * bar = new QBluetoothServer(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommP
    clientConnected(bar);
}
```

Compile with

```
gcc -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Bluetooth` `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Network` -c targettype.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an lvalue (such as from deferencing your `clientsocket` variable) to `decltype()` returns a reference type, so if you want to use `decltype` then you will need to use `std::remove_reference` or `std::remove_pointer` to access the type being referenced, there is just no getting around that.

In C++14 and later, you can use `std::remove_reference_t<T>` instead of `std::remove_reference<T>::type` (or `std::remove_pointer_t<T>` instead of `std::remove_pointer<T>::type`), which will save a few characters:

```cpp
QObject::connect(
    clientsocket,
    &std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*clientsocket)>::disconnected,
    [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); }
);
```

```cpp
QObject::connect(
    clientsocket,
    &std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(clientsocket)>::disconnected,
    [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); }
);
```

If you really want something shorter, you could use a `using` alias:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using no_ref = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
          // = std::remove_reference_t<T>;

QObject::connect(
    clientsocket,
    &no_ref<decltype(*clientsocket)>::disconnected,
    [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); }
);
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
using no_ptr = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;
          // = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;

QObject::connect(
    clientsocket,
    &no_ptr<decltype(clientsocket)>::disconnected,
    [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); }
);
```

In C++17 and later, you could use an `if constexpr` to differentiate between the two types, eg:

```cpp
auto handler = [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); };
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(*clientsocket), QBluetoothSocket&>)
    QObject::connect(clientsocket, &QBluetoothSocket::disconnected, handler);
else
    QObject::connect(clientsocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, handler);
```

However, there is a simpler solution that doesn't involve using `decltype` at all:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using signalType = void(T::*)();

template<typename T>
signalType<T> getDisconnectedSignal(T*)
{
    return &T::disconnected;
}

QObject::connect(
    clientsocket, 
    getDisconnectedSignal(clientsocket),
    [=](){ disconnected(clientsocket); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think i'll go with the c++14 variant, this is a codebase I control completely and that is only likely to be built with modern g++. If I was doing it a lot i'd probablly wrap it in a macro but right now it's just a one-off so that is probablly not worth it. Downvote changed to upvote, I'll wait a bit before accepting in case anyone has better ideas.

Comment: @plugwash I have updated my answer again with another solution that doesn't use `decltype` at all.

Answer (score 2):

just use `std::remove_pointer` (or `std::remove_pointer_t` in C++14).

```cpp
using t = typename std::remove_pointer<int*>::type; // t = int.
```